# Why angular returns with referenceError: ngResource is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I've done quick client-side routing with angular 1.4.4. In every tutorial I saw approach where you assign module to variable (usually: app) and perform different tasks on it, like below:

```
var app = angular.module('skeleton', [ngResource, ngRoute]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                     templateUrl: '/partials/main',
                     controller: 'MainController'
                   });
});

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'Hi Angular';
});
```

In tutorial which I'm doing now I see completely different approach:

```
angular.module('skeleton', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module('skeleton').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
});

angular.module('skeleton').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.test = "Hello Angular";
});
```

I assumed it's just preference, so i went with 'app' version as I find it more readable.
Unfortunately it causes angular to throw

```
ReferenceError: ngResource is not defined
```

1. Anyone know what is cause of this behaviour?
2. Which approach do you prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to to inject dependency properly, pass `ngResource` and `ngRoute` within quotes, otherwise they are treated as variable hence you must be getting the error.

```
var app = angular.module('skeleton', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
```

Comment: Well, that one was silly, thank you :) Do you know any debugging tools or linters that work well with Angular and prevent problems like above?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly , The issue is not with assigning the module declaration to a variable 'app' and then using it. Both approaches work but it is better to declare without assigning it to a variable which avoids variable collisions  which could lead to module overriding.

The issue in your code is the syntax. Please correct it as shown below :

```
var app = angular.module('skeleton', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
```

dependency Annotation can also be done by assigning the array of dependencies to the '$inject' property or directly as the function properties .

Please refer to this angular guide for reference :

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di
```